# Derivation maximization problem

Tags: integration, derivatives, first-order-logic

It's been a while since I've had to do derivations so I'm just a little rusty. I need to understand the steps for deriving (Py – 2)(44 – 2Py + Px) to reach Py = 12 + 0.25Px. Py here is price of product y and Px is the price of product x.

I undertsant that I need to take product rule of the first equation and then set it = 0 and solve for Py, but it's finding that derived equation that's troubling me.

How I tried to do it was to first simplify the equation into 44Py - 2Py^2 + PxPy - 88 + 4Py + 2Px. Then taking the derivative and simplifying a little I end up with 46 - 3Py + Px which I would then set = 0 and solve for Py, giving me Py = (46 + Px)/3. Which is obviously not correct.

If you could help me through the steps to reach Py = 12 + 0.25Px I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of your simplified expression is

$$ 48 - 4P_y + P_x. $$

I think you made two mistakes: an algebra error, so you ended up with $46$ instead of $48$, and forgetting that the derivative of $-2P_y^2$ is $-4P_y$.

Comment: Yes, that'll give me 12 + 0.25 Px = Py. Could you please show me the steps of derivation. I beleive that's where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer. Does that help?